# AJAX - Slide button smoothly down upon div change

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

I want to slide the button smoothly down upon click. I found this jQuery .slideDown() method but I couldn't make it to work. Where should I have to modify?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js'></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    myIdentifier = $.now();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/cd_catalog.xml?uniq=" + myIdentifier,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            $($(xml).find('ARTIST').get().reverse()).slice(0, 3).each(function () {
                artist = ("<p class='artist'>" + $(this).text() + "</p>");
                $(artist).hide().appendTo("#myDiv").fadeIn(1000);
            });
            var ii = 4;
            $('button').click(function () {
                $($(xml).find('ARTIST').get().reverse()).slice(ii, ii + 5).each(function () {
                    artist = ("<p class='artist' style='display:none;'>" + $(this).text() + "</p>");
                    $("#myDiv").append(artist);
                    $('.artist').fadeIn(1000, function () {
                        $(this).css({'visibility':'visible',display:'block'}).slideDown();
                    });

                });
                ii += 5;
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
<button id="button1" type="button">Show More</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are doing a fadeIn and then a slideDown?

Comment: In fact, it doesn't matter. I am just trying to catch some smooth look. I mean, it can start to slide and then fade in...

Comment: It does matter because fadeIn will have already set it to fully visible and full height.  So slideIn will have no visible effect.  All of those effects are simply predefined animations of css properties.  So going from hide() to slideDown() will work, but fadeIn() to any other "show"-type of effect will have no visible results.

Comment: If you want to do both then just try using animate() directly with each of the properties you want it to animate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside your `.fadeIn` function, `$(this)` is reffering to `$('.artist')`. If you want to target the button that you clicked, you have to store that button in a variable, like this:

```
$('button').click(function () {

    clickedBtn = $(this); //save $(this) for later

    //removed some stuff so it's easier to read..
    $('.artist').fadeIn(1000, function () {
        clickedBtn.slideDown(); //slideDown saved element here
    }); 
    //you don't need to set element to visible with css, 
    //slideDown() does this for you
});
```

Comment: That was a great move!

Comment: Text fadeIn lost. Is it not possible?

Comment: actually your main problem was already mentioned in another answer.. have a look at my answer now

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.artist').fadeIn(1000, function () {
    $(this).css({'visibility':'visible',display:'block'}).slideDown();
});
```

Your $(this) is inside a function(fadeIn), now $(this) reference the element $('.artist'), and not $('button');

to resolve *this*, you need save it in a variable:

```
$('button').click(function() {
  btnTarget = $(this); // this reference your $('button')
  ...
  $('.artist').fadeIn(1000, function () {
    // look now:
    btnTarget.css({'visibility':'visible',display:'block'}).slideDown();
  });
})
```